# Sort ArrayList Objects properties with custom start point

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, conditional-statements

My question is about how to sort an ArrayList with custom Object by one of them properties but starting from a custom condition.

Let me explain better, here is my code:

```
public static void sortArrayListByProperty(ArrayList colorList){

        Collections.sort(colorList, new Comparator(){

            public int compare(Object emp1, Object emp2){

                int intValue1 = ((ColorCounter)emp1).getIntColorValue();        
                int intValue2 = ((ColorCounter)emp2).getIntColorValue();

                if(intValue1 < intValue2)
                    return 1;
                else if(intValue1 > intValue2)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;    
            }
        });
    }
```

This will sort my ArrayList from bigger to smaller.

But what I want is to sort my ArrayList from a starting number that I will specify.

For example if ArrayList contains

```
5 3 9 1 14
```

lets say that I want numbers start from 3 then I need to have

```
3 5 9 14 1
```

I hope is clear enought...

Is it possible?

@Joachim Sauer

Thank you, I edited your code a little and changed return values and it worked!

Edited code:

```
if (cv1 >= threshold && cv2 < threshold) {
   return -1;
} else if (cv2 >= threshold && cv2 < threshold) {
   return -1;
} else if (cv1 < cv2) {
   return 1;
} else if (cv1 > cv2) {
   return 1;
} else {
   return 0;    
}
```

Test example:

```
16777215
16448250
15790320
4013373
```

Sorting by 15790320:

```
15790320
16448250
16777215
4013373
```

Comment: Many solutions but I suggest you to use simple patterns like mixing filter and sorting or mixing filter and sorting and merging?

Comment: Why would 1 be bigger than 14? Would every number smaller than 3 be greater than any number greater than 3? How would two numbers smaller than 3 compare to each other?

Comment: what will happen if you add 2, 8, 10 in this list ? What is the logical diffrentiation between these inputs ? I think you are better off adding them in the desired position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public class ColorCounterComparator implements Comparator<ColorCounter> {
  private final threshold;

  public ColorCounterComparator(final int threshold) {
    this.threshold = threshold;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare (ColorCounter c1, ColorCounter c2) {
    int cv1 = c1.getIntColorValue();
    int cv2 = c1.getIntColorValue();

    if (cv1 >= threshold && cv2 < threshold) {
       return -1;
    } else if (cv2 >= threshold && cv2 < threshold) {
       return 1;
    } else if (cv1 < cv2) {
       return -1;
    } else if (cv1 > cv2) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return 0;    
    }
  }
}
```

This is obviously very untested, might have some off-by-one-errors and might have flipped the -1/1 values. But it should show you the basic idea ;-)

Comment: Yup your comparator will have a descending order. If `cv1<cv2` it should return -1. The trick to remember how it should be done is to simply remember to return `value1-value2`; But nice suggestion otherwise.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: thanks, fixed (I hope). That's a neat reminder. But I'd avoid using that construct directly, as there are too many pitfalls associated with it (for example, don't try to use that with floating point numbers, especially if they are close together).

Answer (score 1):

using ArrayList sublist method to create a sub-list, and then sort this sub-list.

Comment: I don't think that this would actually work because imagine you have `3 5 1 9 6 7 2 10` the numbers to actually sort are not contiguous.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I do not understand why this should not work? You can simply get a range of the original list as a view with the subList-method. And you can sort that range - regardless the numbers in that range are contiguous or not.

Comment: @FabianBarney from what I understand, in my example and saying that only values equals or above 3 should be sorted, you should have `3 5 9 6 7 10 1 2`. Now, what sublist indexes would you use if you want to sort such list?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Ah, got it. OP wants a starting point BY VALUE and not by index. Totally misunderstood the question. Sry :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you get the idea: you have 2 situations

- both numbers are below the start number (3 in your example) or both are above ==> compare them
- one number is below the start number, the other above ==> the first one is after the second one in your custom sort order:

---

```
if (intValue1 < start && intValue2 < start || intValue1 >= start && intValue2 >= start) {
    if(intValue1 < intValue2)
        return 1;
    else if(intValue1 > intValue2)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;    
} else {
    if (intValue1 < start)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```